# Perl CGI output

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script for finding the keyword in different types of texts and producing the sorted output.

The present output looks like this

[image: present output]

for a keyword "the".

But I would like to highlight the keyword "the" in bold in this output.

How is it possible to do this?

I tried using `Term::ANSIColor` but it prints the entire sentence in bold and not only the keyword.

My CGI script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# require
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use CGI;
use File::Basename;

my $q = new CGI;
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

#initialize variables
my $target  = $q->param( "keyword" );
my $radius  = $q->param( "span" );
my $ordinal = $q->param( "ord" );
my $width   = 2 * $radius;

#print standard output
print "****************************\n";
print "*      SEARCH RESULTS      *\n";
print "****************************\n";
print "Your Search word is: $target\n\n";
print "Your Radius is     : $radius\n\n";
print "Your Ordinal is    : $ordinal\n\n";
print "-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

#normal concordance for abstract text
my @files = glob( 'ABS/*.txt' );
for my $file ( @files ) {

    my $path      = glob( 'ABS/*.txt' );
    my $file_name = basename( $path );

    # initialize
    my $count = 0;
    my @lines = ();
    $/ = "";    # Paragraph read mode

    # open the file, and process each line in it
    open( FILE, " < $file" ) or die( "Can not open $file ($!).\n" );
    while ( <FILE> ) {

        # re-initialize
        my $extract = '';

        # normalize the data
        chomp;
        s/\n/ /g;           # Replace new lines with spaces
        s/\b--\b/ -- /g;    # Add spaces around dashes

        # process each item if the target is found
        while ( $_ =~ /\b$target\b/gi ) {

            # find start position
            my $match = $1;
            my $pos   = pos;
            my $start = $pos - $radius - length( $match );

            # extract the snippets
            if ( $start < 0 ) {

                $extract = substr( $_, 0, $width + $start + length( $match ) );
                $extract = ( " " x -$start ) . $extract;
            }
            else {

                $extract = substr( $_, $start, $width + length( $match ) );
                my $deficit = $width + length( $match ) - length( $extract );

                if ( $deficit > 0 ) {
                    $extract .= ( " " x $deficit );
                }
            }

            # add the extracted text to the list of lines, and increment
            $lines[$count] = $extract;
            ++$count;

        }
    }

    sub removePunctuation {
        my $string = $_[0];

        $string = lc( $string );     # Convert to lowercase
        $string =~ s/[^-a-z ]//g;    # Remove non-aplhabetic characters
        $string =~ s/--+/ /g;        # Remove 2+ hyphens with a space
        $string =~ s/-//g;           # Remove hyphens
        $string =~ s/\s=/ /g;

        return ( $string );
    }

    sub onLeft {

        #USAGE: $word = onLeft($string, $radius, $ordinal);

        my $left = substr( $_[0], 0, $_[1] );
        $left = removePunctuation( $left );
        my @word = split( /\s+/, $left );

        return ( $word[ -$_[2] ] );
    }

    sub byLeftWords {

        my $left_a = onLeft( $a, $radius, $ordinal );
        my $left_b = onLeft( $b, $radius, $ordinal );

        lc( $left_a ) cmp lc( $left_b );
    }

    # process each line in the list of lines

    my $line_number = 0;
    print "File name: $file_name \n\n";

    foreach my $x ( sort byLeftWords @lines ) {
        ++$line_number;
        printf "%5d", $line_number;
        print " $x\n\n";

    }

    print "------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
}

# done
exit;
```

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're running this from the console, so why are you using CGI?

Comment: Please don't publish text as an image, and you *must always* `use strict` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, especially if you are asking for help with it.

Comment: No I am not running it on the console. I am testing it by local hosting on Apache.

Comment: Okay, but if you saw any effects from `Term::ANSIColor` it would be occasional "nonsense" characters in the page. It could not possibly have produced bold characters in a browser.

Comment: Hey, ya I first test the script in terminal and when I get the desired result I local host it on the Apache. The output image that I have attached is the one produced by local hosting on Apache. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly. Sorry.

Comment: Then that is why you saw bold characters using `Term::ANSIColor`. You may be able to 7 control the console that way but the escape sequences are meaningless to a browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the style of characters displayed in a `text/plain` document. `Term::ANSIColor` certainly won't work as the browser doesn't recognize the ANSI terminal escape sequences, which will work only on your console

If you write your output as HTML then you just need to put `<strong>...</strong>` around the word to be emboldened

Or, better, you can write a CSS style like this

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and wrap the words in `<span class="bold">...</span>`

#### Update

To convert your text document to HTML, the simplest way is to wrap it in a `<pre>...</pre>` ("preformatted") element and put it into the standard HTML structure. Less than `<`, greater than `>` and ampersand `&` characters must be replaced with their corresponding entities `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` respectively, and you can wrap the words you want in **bold** in `<strong>` tags

The minimum HTML5 document which is also friendly with the majority of modern browsers looks like this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <title>Search Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
Content of my report
with words to be in bold wrapped in <strong> tags
and characters `<`, `>`, and `&` replaced by
`&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` respectively
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had already tried producing an HTML output as suggested by you but was unable to get the same output as desired and so I switched to the plain text output. So is there anyway in which I can do this without changing the output to HTML.? Or how can I produce the same output in HTML.? I have problem producing the same kind of output in HTML. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this.